# why getting the menu listing from bottom to top in css?

Tags: html, css

I want a right aligned simple menu.but i am getting the menu listing the li tag from bottom to top. I want to display it from top to bottom in right aligned menu.

html:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li>HOME</li>
  <li>ABOUT</li>
  <li>HOW it WORKS</li>
  <li>SERVICE PROVIDERS</li>
  </ul>
```

css:

```
.menu{
    list-style:none;
}
.menu li{
    float:right;
    padding:10px;
}
```

i am getting the output as the image below
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At-present you are adding `float to li elements` instead add that to `.menu` and change `li display as inline-blocks`, this would be one way of doing this.

Update -

> float:right- The element floats to the right of its container.

As per above statement float right floats element to right-side of container thus here the first li element floats right to the end of container and then followed by other. Add width properties between li tags to understand more clearly and even change the float property to see the difference how elements are floated.

```css
.menu {
  list-style: none;
  float: right; /*Add this*/
}

.menu li {
 display:inline-block; /*Add this*/
 padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>HOME</li>
  <li>ABOUT</li>
  <li>HOW it WORKS</li>
  <li>SERVICE PROVIDERS</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Welcome @liza  please check update to understand more about float.